# Bar plot of non-numerical data in R

Tags: r, plot

How would I do a bar plot of the frequency of non-numerical data using R?

e.g. if given `v = c("B","A","B","A","B","D","C","D","D","D","C")`

I want to get a bar plot in which each bar represents a unique value from the vector and the height of each bar to correspond with the frequency of that value:

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Calculate the table of values for the barplot using the `table()` function, e.g.:

```
v <- c("B","A","B","A","B","D","C","D","D","D","C")
barplot(table(v))
```

This produces

[image: barplot example figure]